# DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact after tab goes out of focus

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-audio

I'm building a website that has various recurring timers. When a timer goes off it plays a short audio notification.

Initially, everything works well. However, after the user minimizes the window and it stays idle for some time the audio playback begins to throw the following error.

> Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.

It seems that after some random amount of time the initial user interaction that was made to get the audio working gets reset and the user needs to interact with the website again to keep the audio notifications to play.

This is clearly and issue but I haven't been able to find anything to fix this specific problem.

I'm loading and playing the audio via the HTML5 Audio API

```
// initiate audio object
const audio = new Audio('/audio/ping.mp3') 
// after some time a timer calls
audio.play()
```

Any insight or a push in the right direction would be much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think this is a deliberate design to prevent background tabs from auto-playing.

Comment: I don't believe there's much, if anything, you can do to work around this. The DOM interaction rules regarding the playing of media is strictly controlled by the browser.

Comment: any idea music sites such as soundcloud get around this? They seem to continuously keep playing without follow-up user interaction.

Comment: I suspect that if you play continuous audio (it can be silent), and mix and sequence your audio into this audio stream, you'll probably be good. Non-trivial, for sure. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API/Advanced_techniques looks like a good place to start. I wonder if generating a silent, non-stop sound would be enough prevent the permission timeout?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking about this for some time and I've designed a solution for myself. It's very hacky and not pretty, but it works.

Also please use this ethically. In my case I do still ask for the user's permission to play the audio and then record the response in local storage so that it would play any time they refresh the page, but they can still disable it back.

First of all, it's not random. Autoplay is gated by user activation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/User_activation. You can't autoplay an audio right after the page loads.

But! You can check if any of the user activation events (the list is available in the docs I've linked) have passed and then play your audio:

```
let audio;

// call this in the root or something
function playAudio() {
  if (!audio) {
    audio = new Audio('YOUR_URL');
  }
  // check for user activation first to avoid the error
  if (navigator.userActivation.hasBeenActive) {
    bgAudio.play();
  } else {
    trackUserActivation();
  }
}

function trackUserActivation() {
    addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    addEventListener('mousedown', onUserActivation, {once: true});
    addEventListener('pointerdown', onPointerDown);
    addEventListener('pointerup', onPointerUp);
    addEventListener('touchend', onUserActivation, {once: true});
}

function onKeyDown(event) {
    // ignore the ESC key
    if (event.keyCode === 27) {
        return;
    }
    onUserActivation();
}

function onPointerDown(event) {
    if (event.pointerType !== 'mouse') {
        return;
    }
    onUserActivation();
}

function onPointerUp(event) {
    if (event.pointerType === 'mouse') {
        return;
    }
    onUserActivation();
}

function onUserActivation() {
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
    }
    removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
    removeEventListener('mousedown', onUserActivation);
    removeEventListener('pointerdown', onPointerDown);
    removeEventListener('pointerup', onPointerUp);
    removeEventListener('touchend', onUserActivation);
}
```

Now whenever the user clicks, taps, presses something on the page, the audio will play.

Comment: Thanks! I have actually dealt with the initial interaction issue by attempting to play audio in a try-catch loop until the audio can play.

My primary issue is the browser seems to have a timeout for the interaction after the users drops the window out of focus. The user then has to interact again with the site to keep the browser happy after some time. That's not ideal. 

I've managed to get around this by playing continuous muted audio after the first interaction, but that's not a great solution, in my opinion.